How to count the number of files related to a record?
I had assumed that DLRS would handle this case. There is an open issue on this area but with rays of hope - thread here https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/issues/433. But I get this error from the call into the package so pretty clear that DLRS is not the answer:
DLRS does not support this object yet: ContentDocumentLink

What is a good alternative?

Do you want to roll up to any parent, or just a specific type?

Hi @sfdcfox, There are 3 parents I care about; think I can make your solution more generic. Thanks!

ContentDocumentLink has special limitations, so you have to take care to follow the rules. However, it is also relatively easy to implement. I wrote this as a trigger for demonstration purposes, but, of course, I recommend a trigger framework if you have one.
This example rolls up to the Account object, but you can roll up to any type of object that can be linked just by changing the relevant data types. You can also make it completely generic to work with all or multiple sObjects.
trigger sumAccountFileCount on ContentDocumentLink (after insert, after delete) {
    Map<Id, Account> accountsById = new Map<Id, Account>();
    for(COntentDocumentLink record: Trigger.isInsert? Trigger.new: Trigger.old) {
        if(record.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType() == Account.sObjectType) {
            accountsById.put(record.LinkedEntityId, new Account(Id=record.LinkedEntityId, File_Count__c=0));
        }
    }
    // Avoids the "Implementation restriction" error when map is empty
    if(accountsById.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    for(AggregateResult record: [
        SELECT LinkedEntityId Id, COUNT(Id) sum
        FROM ContentDocumentLink
        WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :accountsById.keySet()
        GROUP BY LinkedEntityId
    ]) {
        accountsById.get((Id)record.get('Id')).File_Count__c = 
          (Integer)record.get('sum');
    }
    update accountsById.values();
}


Looks like ContentDocumentLink is also "special" in that "Delete" of the file does not result in the ContentDocumentLink after delete trigger running. "Remove from Record" does though. So the delete case likely needs an extra ContentDocument trigger.

All good with the extra trigger I posted as an answer.

I had to add this extra trigger because a "Delete" of a File did not cause the  ContentDocumentLink trigger to run (whether after delete or before delete) though a "Remove from Record" does.
The slightly awkward part here is that it has to be a before delete trigger hence excluding the ContentDocumentLink ids that will be deleted from the count.
trigger ContentDocumentFileCount on ContentDocument (before delete) {

    Map<Id, Account> byId = new Map<Id, Account>();
    Set<Id> beingDeletedCdlIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (ContentDocumentLink cdl: [
        select Id, LinkedEntityId
        from ContentDocumentLink
        where ContentDocumentId in :Trigger.oldMap.keySet()
    ]) {
        if (cdl.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType() == Account.sObjectType) {
            byId.put(cdl.LinkedEntityId, new Account(
                Id = cdl.LinkedEntityId,
                File_Count__c = 0
            ));
            beingDeletedCdlIds.add(cdl.Id);
        }
    }

    // Avoids the "Implementation restriction" error when map is empty
    if (byId.isEmpty())  return;

    for(AggregateResult ar: [
        select LinkedEntityId id, COUNT(Id) sum
        from ContentDocumentLink
        where LinkedEntityId in :byId.keySet()
        and Id not in :beingDeletedCdlIds
        group by LinkedEntityId
    ]) {
        byId.get((Id) ar.get('id')).File_Count__c = (Integer) ar.get('sum');
    }
    update byId.values();
}

PS
Code handling several types:
trigger ContentDocumentFileCount on ContentDocument (before delete) {

    Set<Id> linkedEntityIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> beingDeletedCdlIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (ContentDocumentLink cdl: [
        select Id, LinkedEntityId
        from ContentDocumentLink
        where ContentDocumentId in :Trigger.oldMap.keySet()
    ]) {
        SObjectType t = cdl.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType();
        Boolean ofInterest = t == Aaa__c.sObjectType
            || t == Bbb__c.sObjectType
            || t == Ccc__c.sObjectType
            || t == Ddd__c.sObjectType;
        if (ofInterest) {
            linkedEntityIds.add(cdl.LinkedEntityId);
            beingDeletedCdlIds.add(cdl.Id);
        }
    }

    if (linkedEntityIds.isEmpty())  return;

    SObject[] updates = new SObject[] {};

    for(AggregateResult ar: [
        select LinkedEntityId id, COUNT(Id) sum
        from ContentDocumentLink
        where LinkedEntityId in :linkedEntityIds
        and Id not in :beingDeletedCdlIds
        group by LinkedEntityId
    ]) {
        Id id = (Id) ar.get('id');  
        Integer sum = (Integer) ar.get('sum');
        SObjectType t = id.getSObjectType();
        SObject r = t.newSObject(id);
        r.put('File_Count__c', sum);
        updates.add(r);
    }

    // Minimize the chunks of records that are updated
    updates.sort(new Util.RecordTypeComparator());
    update updates;
}

